# opencv program data to a excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, opencv

I am currently doing a project on image filtering by colours using opencv with python on OSX. I have made a functioning program that when it finds the object of a specific color, it prints a message in terminal that says "found box" and the pixel size in that frame.

My question is that when I try to write this data in a excel sheet using xlwrt, it prints out the size of the pixel, but it is constantly overwritten in the same cell. I would rather that all my pixel size values would appear in the column set for pixel.

Here is part of the program

```
  kernel = np.ones((31,31),np.uint8);
  opening=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel,0);
  kernel = np.ones((17,17),np.uint8);
  dilation=cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=2);
  opening=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel,2);
  edges = cv2.Canny(mask,100,255)
  contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(opening,1,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
  res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= dilation)
  #contours=np.zeros(mask.shape,np.uint8);
  areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
  ar = 0.0
  i = 0

  book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

  sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1", cell_overwrite_ok=False)

  sheet1.write(0, 0, "Frame")
  sheet1.write(0, 1, "Pixel")

  list1 = [0]

  for a in areas:
    print(a);
    i += 1
    ar=float(a)
    list1.append(ar)
    sheet1.write(i,0,ar)
    book.save("/Users/canogerardo55/Desktop/trial.xls")
    if (a>10000):
        print("found box");
        break;
```

Comment: When doing something similar I typically write to a csv.  It's simpler and you can always open it with excel if you really want to.